# How long is a DataFrame cached?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please help me understanding the scope of the cached dataframe within another function.

Example:

```
def mydf(): DataFrame = {
    val df = sparkSession.sql("select * from emp")
    df.cache() // <-- cached here
    df
}

def joinWithDept(): Unit = {
    val deptdf1 = sparkSession.sql("select * from dept")
    val deptdf2 = mydf().join(deptdf1,Seq("empid")) // <-- using the cached dataset?
    deptdf2.show()
}

def joinWithLocation() : Unit = {
    val locdf1 = sparkSession.sql("select * from from location")
    val locdf2 = mydf().join(locdf1,Seq("empid")) // <-- using the cached dataset?
    locdf2.show()
}

def run(): Unit = {
    joinWithDept()
    joinWithLocation()
}
```

All above functions are defined in same class. I not sure, if will get the benefit of dataframe caching performed in mydf() function? How to do I verify that it is getting the benefit of catching?

Answer (score 0):

`joinWithDept` and `joinWithLocation` will both use the (cached logical query plan) of the `DataFrame` from `mydf()`.

You can check the cached DataFrame in Storage tab of web UI.

You can also verify that the joins use the cached dataframe by reviewing physical query plans (by `explain` or in web UI) where you should see `InMemoryRelations` used.